# Updating a table based on contents of the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
id, number, name, display_name

0001, 1, Category 1, null
0001-0002, 2, Category 2, null
0001-0002-0003, 3, Category 3, null
```

The id is the full path to the category, the number is just the final category number.
I'd like display_name updated to include the full names from all categories in the path, so they'd end up as

```
0001, 1, Category 1, Category 1
0001-0002, 2, Category 2, Category 1 > Category 2
0001-0002-0003, 3, Category 3, Category 1 > Category 2 > Category 3
```

I know I can generate these on the fly by lookups to the number column, but this table doesn't need to change that often but it has a lot of lookups -- it seems wasteful not to just calculate and store the data once. I can do this in php but it's slow and I assume there's a better way to do it? Or perhaps I'm just going about this in completely the wrong way. I realise there's plenty of redundancy in the table... I'm happy for any input.

I got as far as

```
update categories set display=(select name from (select name from categories where number=1) t) where number=1
```

but that obviously just copies the name to the display name.

Comment: Normalize your table and you won't have the above headache.

Comment: I'm basing this data off a third party source so I'm restricted as to what I can do with it. That said, the data is normalized, I'm just denormalizing for performance reasons.

Comment: How many levels do you have?